# How can I bind a Bluetooth keyboard to a dongle, but not the internal built-in bluetooth. The keyboard for use in a kvm switch

Tags: usb, keyboard, bluetooth, kvm-virtualization

My setup:

Two docked laptops connected to a TeSmart 2-Way dual monitor KVM switch:

1. a dell laptop running on windows
2. a lambda labs laptop running on ubuntu.

I have a cheapo red-dragon wireless mouse that came with it's own dongle, which works fine in the mouse port in the kvm switch.

I also have an AZIO keyboard that has a few key features:

1. The keyboard can be connected to via USB (my current implementation)
2. The keyboard has a bluetooth mode, which can support up to three different devices.

THE PROBLEM:
I want to connect my keyboard to a dongle, so that I can then plug the dongle into the keyboard port of the KVM like my mouse is.  I can use the multi-device option of the keyboard, but that's not as abstract as having it "bound" to the kvm switch.

***WHAT I WANT TO DO IS TO BIND MY KEYBOARD TO THE DONGLE***, like how my mouse is bound to the dongle that came with it.  I pretty much want to plug my dongle into the keyboard port of the KVM, and connecte the laptop to the dongle, rather than the built-in bluetooth of my ubuntu laptop.

Since my both my laptops have built-in bluetooth, I'm stumped as to how to even attempt to do this.  I would like to think that I can achieve this on my ubuntu laptop, since Linux allows you to do anything with your machine.

Surely a simple solution exists, but I am relatively new to manipulating devices on Linux, let alone devices with separate bluetooth capabilities.

Comment: it is different from keyboard to keyboard, so check the manual. if it doesn't say about binding to the dongle anything i don't know how do it otherwise by the dongle. the only solution i can give is by using Bluetooth.

Comment: The above comment is a word salad. Nothing useful. And no, there isn't a simple solution, actually no solution at all for what you want to do.

Comment: Maybe you can turn off bluetooth in your BIOS/UEFI settings, then attach the kb to the dongle, which should be the only bluetooth host seen. Then you should be able to turn on bluetooth in the BIOS again. The settings are in /var/lib/bluetooth/<MACofServer>/<MAC ofDevice>/info.  Maybe you can just move the <MACofDevice> dir to the other server MAC.